# Статьи по созданию игр на js

Tags: javascript

Помогите найти статьи по созданию игр на js, но только с очень понятно изложенным материалом. Перед созданием этой темы я поискал в гугле, но к сожалению находил лишь статьи, предназначенные для создания сайтов на js, а не игр.

Comment: Как-раз хотел задать такой-же вопрос :)

Comment: и надо вам с кроссбраузерностью заморачиваться?

Comment: мне не надо, строго под адекватные браузеры... На IE наплевать...

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Зачем вам такие статьи? Учитье JavaScript как язык и разбирайтесь в HTML5/CSS3/SVG и получите всё необходимое для создания игр.

Answer (score 1):

Вот несколько примеров:

http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1020

http://forum.htmlbook.ru/index.php?showtopic=21246

http://sources.ru/magazine/0906/01.html

И, если Вам посчастливиться, купите или скачайте эту книгу 
http://www.apress.com/9781430233831. В ней рассматривается создание нескольких игр средствами JavaScript и HTML5

P.S. Ссылку на книгу, если что, бросьте сюда

Answer (score 0):

Статьи о создании игр на Java Script, HTML5, SVG, WebGL http://2l4udotru.blogspot.ru/